# nib but didn't get a UICollectionView IOS7

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hi in my application i have `UICollectionView` in that I'm displaying the images form the server using `JSON`. Now I'm getting error while I'm trying to display the images in the detailViewController when click on the `UICollectionViewCell` like.

```
2014-05-23 15:27:55.097 filcker[1836:70b] *** Assertion failure in-[detailimagepoliticalViewController loadView], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.23      /UICollectionViewController.m:166
2014-05-23 15:27:55.098 filcker[1836:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewController loadView] loaded the "tuG-0Q-NNM-view-150-NJ-MMy" nib but didn't get a UICollectionView.'
```

I'm getting this above error but i have already connected the data source and delegate method the the UICollectionView.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "imggpolitical.h"
#import "detailimagepoliticalViewController.h"
  @interface imagepoliticalViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource>

  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionview;
```

In prepareForSegue i have coded like this.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"photoview"]){
   imggpolitical *cell = (imggpolitical *)sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionview indexPathForCell:cell];

    detailimagepoliticalViewController *idvc =(detailimagepoliticalViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
    idvc.img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[photoids objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]]];       
   }

  }
```

UICollection Code.

```
 -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    return [photoids count];
 }
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


   static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"Cell";


  imggpolitical *cell=(imggpolitical *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath: indexPath];


  cell.imageview.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[photoids objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]]];

  return cell;
}
```

This are steps i have done but its not working please tell me how to resolve this issues.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the nib: tuG-0Q-NNM-view-150-NJ-MMy a subclass of UICollectionView? Also can you show code for the didSelectItem method for your UICollectionView.

Comment: @Tander i did't use any subclass for uicollectionview i have only imported the detailview controller and uicollectionviewcell files thats all

Comment: @Tander i didt use the didselectitem method here

Comment: Then how do you trigger prepareForSegue method

Comment: Check the views connection to the files owner

Comment: @Tander i dont know how to use the didselect method in uicollectionview im new to the ios development

Comment: @NandakumarR i have already checked evethying connected prefectly

Comment: I assume you have a UICollectionView with some cells that display some stuff. You then tap on a cell to go to details view... where is the code that checks which cell was tapped and how do you invoke the prepareForSegue method?

Comment: @Tander please check my question i have edited

Comment: That code is find for displaying your images. It still doesn't show me how you call: prepareForSegue method and how you get to detailsViewController. The class imggpolitical is a subclass of UICollectionView, right?

Comment: @Tander imggpolitical is my uicollectioncell class i have imported into my h file of uicollectionview and as like as same i have importeded detailviewcontroller in .h file

Comment: What is the `@interface` definition for `detailimagepoliticalViewController`?  What does it subclass?

Comment: @Paulw11 its a subclass for uicollection to display the image

Comment: Please post the exact @interface line as you have done for `imagepoliticalViewController`

Comment: detailimagepoliticalViewController should not be a subclass of UICollectionView. At the very least, it should be UIViewController

Comment: @Tander its a uiviewcontroller only i have just imported

Comment: @Paulw11 pleaes check my question i have edited now

Comment: @Paulw11 i forgot to tell that detailimage is UIviewcontroller

Comment: I still don't see a line in your question `@interface detailimagepoliticalViewController <...`

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks paulw in figure out the problem in detailimage interface its instead of uiviewcontrolller is showing the uicollectionview

Comment: @Tander thanks for u help  figure out the problem in detailimage interface its instead of uiviewcontrolller is showing the uicollectionview